# serialize class to xml

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm trying to serialize an object (class) to Xml, because I need to send it to JDE Business Function.
I have problems when I need to represent an arraylist like this:

```
<params>
<param name='szGroup'>val1</param>
<param name='szOWPassword'>val2</param>
...
</params>
```

In my class I created this:

```
...
[XmlArray("params")]
[XmlArrayItem("param")]
public List<Param> Param {get; set;}
...

public class Param
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

But I get this:

```
<params>
  <param name="szGroup" />
  <param name="szOWPassword" />...
```

Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Where are you expecting those values to come from? I don't see them anywhere.

Comment: You must create your object from that class and add values to it. Then serialize this object and you have values there :) Good example http://tech.pro/tutorial/798/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization

Comment: Are you instantiating the object and setting the values in the properties before you serialize?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`XmlText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute:

```
public class Param
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This will do it. Also, if you don't want indention you can specify that in the `XmlWriterSettings` object (`Indent = false`).  If you need the full end element `</param>` instead of `<param=.../>` you will have to subclass `XmlTextWriter` and override `WriteEndElement()` method to call `base.WriteFullEndElement()`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you need to serialize, it may be wise to subclass `XmlTextWriter` in your case to have more control over the serialization. If you *must* have the full ending elements, this is one of the easiest ways to accomplish that:

```
public class MyXmlTextWriter : XmlTextWriter
{
  public MyXmlTextWriter(TextWriter writer) : base(writer) { }

  public override void WriteEndElement()
  {
    base.WriteFullEndElement();
  }

  // Override any additional XML serialization methods.
}
```

Then you would just instantiate `MyXmlTextWriter` instead and use it to serialize your XML.